# OpenGL 2.0 ES Android Draw Rectangle

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm following Google's tutorial (http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/environment.html) and i think that i everything correctly done. But i have problem, Triangle and Rectangle is invisible and LogCat doesn't show any error.
This is my code for rectangle:

```
package com.example.gameengine;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;

import android.opengl.GLES20;

/**
 * A two-dimensional square for use as a drawn object in OpenGL ES 2.0.
 */
public class GLObject {

    private final String vertexShaderCode =
            // This matrix member variable provides a hook to manipulate
            // the coordinates of the objects that use this vertex shader
            "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
            "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
            "void main() {" +
            // The matrix must be included as a modifier of gl_Position.
            // Note that the uMVPMatrix factor *must be first* in order
            // for the matrix multiplication product to be correct.
            "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
            "}";

    private final String fragmentShaderCode =
            "precision mediump float;" +
            "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
            "void main() {" +
            "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
            "}";

    private final FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    private final ShortBuffer drawListBuffer;
    private final int mProgram;
    private int mPositionHandle;
    private int mColorHandle;
    private int mMVPMatrixHandle;

    // number of coordinates per vertex in this array
    static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
    static float squareCoords[] = {
            -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   // top left
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   // bottom left
             0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   // bottom right
             0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f }; // top right

    private final short drawOrder[] = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 }; // order to draw vertices

    private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; // 4 bytes per vertex

    float color[] = { 0.2f, 0.709803922f, 0.898039216f, 1.0f };

    /**
     * Sets up the drawing object data for use in an OpenGL ES context.
     */
    public GLObject() {
        // initialize vertex byte buffer for shape coordinates
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
        // (# of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
                squareCoords.length * 4);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
        vertexBuffer.put(squareCoords);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);

        // initialize byte buffer for the draw list
        ByteBuffer dlb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
                // (# of coordinate values * 2 bytes per short)
                drawOrder.length * 2);
        dlb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        drawListBuffer = dlb.asShortBuffer();
        drawListBuffer.put(drawOrder);
        drawListBuffer.position(0);

        // prepare shaders and OpenGL program
        int vertexShader = GLRenderer.loadShader(
                GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
                vertexShaderCode);
        int fragmentShader = GLRenderer.loadShader(
                GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
                fragmentShaderCode);

        mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();             // create empty OpenGL Program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);   // add the vertex shader to program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader); // add the fragment shader to program
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);                  // create OpenGL program executables
    }

    /**
     * Encapsulates the OpenGL ES instructions for drawing this shape.
     *
     * @param mvpMatrix - The Model View Project matrix in which to draw
     * this shape.
     */
    public void draw(float[] mvpMatrix) {
        // Add program to OpenGL environment
        GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

        // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
        mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");

        // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

        // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(
                mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
                GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                vertexStride, vertexBuffer);

        // get handle to fragment shader's vColor member
        mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");

        // Set color for drawing the triangle
        GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0);

        // get handle to shape's transformation matrix
        mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
        GLRenderer.checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");

        // Apply the projection and view transformation
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);
        GLRenderer.checkGlError("glUniformMatrix4fv");

        // Draw the square
        GLES20.glDrawElements(
                GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, drawOrder.length,
                GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);

        // Disable vertex array
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    }

}
```

And this is how i draw rectangle:

```
GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Set the camera position (View matrix)
        Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -3, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

        // Calculate the projection and view transformation
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);

        // Draw square
        mSquare.draw(mMVPMatrix);
```

GLSurface is correctly implmenent(i can change background color)

Comment: Those vertices appear to be in NDC space, yet you clearly have a non-identity ModelViewProjection matrix in this example. You are probably just transforming the vertices out of your viewing volume.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Since vertex buffer objects are not being used for drawing here, no need to use the ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER. That being the case, have you tried just specifying an unit matrix for the mvp that will show the quad without any transformation ? That will rule out the possibility of the quad not getting drawn at all and hence being invisible.

Is this the full drawing code ? It looks like you are not binding the ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, that is needed for indexing the vertices using `drawListBuffer`.

Using the below, you can enable this for the default object (0).

`glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, somebufferID);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, someotherBufferID);`

Comment: The code you give does not enable anything. There is no "default" buffer object.

Comment: Where did I say default buffer object ?

Comment: There is also no "default object" which you can bind via `glBindBuffer(...,0)`. The code you give is in no way different from never binding any of those buffer objects at all, and is not enabling anything.

Comment: I went back and checked the OP's code, and realised vertex buffer objects were not even used. Got used to seeing the index based approach that this was the first thing that came to mind. Edited now.